# frame.add (label, JFrame.TOP) error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jframe, jlabel

i get an error of Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position. It works when i do frame.add(label, JFrame.CENTER) but when i change it
it dosnt work.

```
package com.java;

import javax.swing.*;

import sun.audio.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class PlayClip extends JFrame{

public static void frame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("COLLIN");
    frame.setSize(1086, 1200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:MYFILE");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(label, JLabel.BOTTOM);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    frame();
}
}
```

Comment: "TOP" doesn't even appear in this code.

Comment: @tieTYT where it says frame.add(label, JLabel.BOTTOM) if i did top i would get an error. for some reason it only works when i do frame.add(label, JLabel,CENTER).

Comment: Please do not delete your question or turn it into nonsense. This is not fair to those that have volunteered their time to help you, and certainly not fair to those in the future who search this site for answers to similar questions. I have rolled back your question to the original state and will do so again and notify the moderators if you try this trick again. If you make a habit of doing this and no one will want to help you. Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `frame.add(label, JLabel.BOTTOM);` wrong.  The documentation says:

> **comp** - the component to be added
>
> **index** - the position at which to insert the component, or -1 to append the component to the end

`JFrame.CENTER` equals 0, by coincidence.  That's why it works.  `TOP` and `BOTTOM` are 1 and 3, respectively.  When you use those, it's like getting an index out of bounds error on an array/list.

You should look into using a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) because this method isn't for what you think it's for.

---

This proof of concept probably does what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("COLLIN");
    frame.setSize(1086, 1200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("my text", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @user2498848 - In stackoverflow you thank for correct answers by accepting them.

Answer (score 0):

In line `frame.add(label, JLabel.BOTTOM);` you are assigning an alignment option for `frame`, not for `JLabel`. So you should use the constants from `JFrame`, and not `JLabel`.

The constants of `JLabel` are used to align the text inside the label.

Use `frame.add(label)`. That should be enough.